# Composer: file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php, sudo

I'm trying to install [Prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) to an Ubuntu 16.04 server, but that leads to an error:

```
$ composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3"
Changed current directory to /home/kramer65/.composer


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I'm logged in as user `kramer65`, so I wouldn't know why it can't write to my home folder. My normal reaction to a `permission denied` is to use `sudo`, but composer then always says:

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: May be obvious, but must be asked...what are the current permissions on your `composer.json`?

Comment: @GentlemanMax - There is no `~/.composer/composer.json` file yet.

Comment: So what are the permissions on `~/.composer/` folder? `kramer65` has no right to write it seems, a `chmod` could be useful.

Comment: @AnthonyB - Yes, I now see `~/.composer/` is owned by `root`. But I just checked on some other systems and installed composer on a fresh new Ubuntu 16.04 VM, and it is always owned by `root`. I can of course `chmod` or `chown` it , but is it a good idea to change this default behaviour?

Comment: I just checked on my Ubuntu 16.04, indeed .composer is owned by root, with `755` mode. So change owner is probably not the solution.

Comment: Not totally related, but I wouldn't install Prestissimo on a production server. It's compatibility with newer versions of Composer might require updates that you probably don't want to deal with in production.

Comment: @Dwight - I was actually installing prestissimo to a production server because I want deployments of new updates to go as fast possible so that downtime is as short as possible. But you would absolutely recommend against installing prestissimo to a production server?

Comment: @kramer65 I would, just because I've run into some trouble with it locally playing up with new releases of Composer. I'm sure those issues will go as it matures though. Also, if you use a sensible `composer install` on your server it can go quite quick... something like `composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist` which would skip development dependencies and download distribution releases should make it a lot quicker than normal.

Comment: I had the same problem, I simply did ```create new composer.lock file with an empty valid json content``` then re-run the up --build docker. And it worked !

Answer (score 296, accepted):

I had this problem to install laravel/lumen.

It can be resolved with the following command:

```
$ sudo chown -R "$(id -un)" "$(composer config --global home)"
```

What this command does: Execute as privileged user (root) the command to change file owner (not group) to the current user (by name) recursively to the [COMPOSER_HOME](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) directory.

As the user-name as well as the composer home directory can be different on each system, the following two commands are in use to obtain the ...

1. ... username: `id -un`
2. ... composer home directory: `composer config --global home`

---

This is an old question, and so a reader of the answer may want to become aware of the following:

- *Prestissimo* was dedicated to be used with Composer 1
- As of today, Composer 2 has been released which already didn't benefit from *Prestissimo* any longer.
- But even further as of today, Composer 2.2 has been released which is a Long Term Support (LTS) version you should replace Composer 1 with immediatly *if* you deemed it to require *Presstissimo* in the past as it is in general and overall much more faster than Composer 1 ever was - with or without *Prestissimo*.

How to continue:

1. Remove *Prestissmo* from any of your systems.
2. Replace Composer 1 with Composer 2.2 on any of your systems.
3. Enjoy.

Comment: THis also worked for me in yii2 installation of composer global asset plugin thanks samuel

Comment: Using $USER instead of 'myuser' is better option.

Comment: It didn't fix the problem for me, strange. Any other tips?

Comment: @mylord Make sure that the .composer is from your user. Try run with `~/.composer`

Comment: This is a good tip. However if you have already created your project run sudo chown -R $USER my_project

Comment: sudo chown -R $(id -un) ~/.composer/

Answer (score 19):

To resolve this, you should open up a terminal window and type this command:

`sudo chown -R user ~/.composer` (with `user` being your current user, in your case, `kramer65`)

After you have ran this command, you should have permission to run your composer global require command.

You may also need to remove the .composer file from the current directory, to do this open up a terminal window and type this command:

`sudo rm -rf .composer`

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? What is the benefit of removing the .composer file you suggest at the end of the answer and when would it be that this is also needed? Wouldn't it render the first answered chown'ing needless? Can you elaborate on that a bit, I think it would improve your answer.

Answer (score 12):

For me, in Ubuntu 18.04. I needed to chown inside `~/.config/composer/`

E.g.

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/composer
```

Then global commands work.

Comment: How is that different from the accepted answer? Wouldn't the accepted suggested recursive chowning on ~/.config also do yours suggested recursive chowning on ~/.config/composer? What is the benefit of your answer over the longtime accepted one so that you in Dec 2020 considered it requires an additional answer?

Comment: @hakre `$ sudo chown -R "$(id -un)" ~/.composer/` is not targeting  `~/.config/composer`... is it?

Comment: True, this is the old name and it *might* still be the fall-back. We should document that properly. IIRC we're looking for `$(composer config home)`. It gives the correct path regardless which version/installation.

Comment: So I conflated .composer with .config that time. I stand corrected. The actual command to obtain the folder according to Composer docs is `$(composer config --global home)` btw.. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 10):

In my case I don't have issues with `~/.composer`.
So being inside Laravel app root folder, I did `sudo chown -R $USER composer.lock` and it was helpful.

Comment: Actually you should keep deploying/installing the application into the webroot apart from composer install. Then you don't run into the problem you answer here (which is independent to the question that is about COMPOSER_HOME not the webroot folder).

Comment: Yes, and thinking: The answer is actually the existing one when _where_ is of less concern, e.g. `sudo chown`  works, the recipe is the same in the existing answer, and the duplication is not helpful (IMHO). The comment was for your info that you can benefit in your situation by divide and conquer: it is likely that you have a different problem (just the solution with sudo chown works). That is with all due respect, not saying there is anything inherently wrong with your solution, it is just the context. Please let me know if that is understandable / helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue as well but in my case, I was in wrong directory. Check the directory you are working

Answer (score 5):

In my case all the permissions were correct at all the locations manetioned in other answers here, but I was still getting this error.

Turned out there were some vendor directories that were owned by root. Composer writes `composer.lock` files *all over the place* when it's doing an update or install.

So solving my case - and this is specifically for a laravel sail container - all ownerships were switched to user `sail` in the project:

Enter the `sail` container as root:

```
vendor/bin/sail root-shell
```

Set the file ownership for all files in the project:

```
chown -R sail:sail /var/www/html
```

You may just want to do the vendor directory only as a first try:

```
chown -R sail:sail /var/www/html/vendor
```

The ownership was wrong after switching from a hand-rolled `docker-compose.yaml` setup to Laravel Sail, which IMO handles file ownership and permissions in a sensible way, separating `root` from the application user `sail`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `.composer` was owned by root, so I did `sudo rm -fr .composer` and then my global require worked.

**Be warned!** You don't wanna use that command if you are not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

This might be super edge case, but if you are using Travis CI and taking advantage of caching, you might want to clear all cache and retry.

Fixed my issue when I was going from sudo to non sudo builds.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception, but in my case I am using PowerShell to run commands
So, I fixed this with an instruction to unblock multiple files first.
`PS C:\> dir C:\executable_file_Path\*PowerShell* | Unblock-File`
and then use the following to load the package
`& 'C:\path_to_executable\php.exe' "c:\path_to_composer_.phar_file\composer.phar "require desired/package`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using it with WSL Windows 10. I used the following command to solve it:-

```
sudo chown -R $USER  /home/<username>/.config/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in windows version of composer that has installed in

> C:\composer

When I was trying this command

> C:\composer require aws/aws-sdk-php

then simply I got into composer installed folder and try it again

> C:\composer>composer require aws/aws-sdk-php

the package installed quickly .

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I was running the `composer require` inside `/var/www/html` ,the default root folder of the apache web server and I was able to solve it by making the current user the owner of this html directory by

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html
```

But you definitely want to set the permissions

```
chmod 755 -R /var/www/html
```

Comment: Actually you should keep deploying/installing the application into the webroot apart from composer require or composer install. Then you don't run into the problem you answer here (which is independent to the question that is about COMPOSER_HOME not the webroot folder).

Comment: @hakre, I shared what worked for me. Perhaps it isn't useful for champions like you, but I felt compelled to share it in the hopes that it might help someone like me.

Comment: Well that is actually what also was my impression: "worked for me" and that you felt compelled to share that. It's just misplaced, this question asks about the global composer directory, a.k.a. COMPOSER_HOME, not /var/www/html or a similar working directory when installing. This is less or not at all even about me being a champion, however thanks for the flowers.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I used `sudo mkdir projectFolder` to create folder. It was owned by root user and I was logged in using non root user.

So I changed the folder permission using command `sudo chown mynonrootuser:mynonrootuser projectFolder` and then it worked fine.

Comment: Sure, the mistake was to `sudo mkdir projectFolder` in the first place. But how is that related to the question asked here?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 components to consider.

Composer wants you to run it as the logged in user.  However, your webserver wants to have permissions over your application.

The solution is to add your user to the webserver group, then update the permissions of your application.

For Ubuntu running Apache webserver, use the following command to add yourself to the Apache group, replacing `<username>` with your username

```
    sudo usermod -a -G www-data <username>
```

Now you need to update your permissions on your application.  Navigate to the root folder of your application and use the following command

```
    sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .
```

Composer now has the necessary permissions to pull in the packages you need and Apache has the necessary permissions to deliver your application.

Comment: Actually you should keep deploying/installing the application into the webroot apart from composer install. Then you don't run into the problem you answer here (which is independent to the question that is about COMPOSER_HOME not the webroot folder).