# Installed composer globally in my localhost, now I get "file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied"?

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php

I've installed composer globally. After the download, I've followed [the instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) and added:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

So, now, I'm getting in the folder `/var/www/html/buscador` and tried to [install a project](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php#-installation). The Github instruction indicates that I should use:

```
composer require meilisearch/meilisearch-php guzzlehttp/guzzle http-interop/http-factory-guzzle:^1.0
```

But using it I get:

> file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream:
> Permission denied

I've looked for [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212362/composer-file-put-contents-composer-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission) to this, so I've tried this: (*rosamunda* is my user)

```
sudo chown -R rosamunda ~/.composer/
```

It ask for my password and then I get:

> chown: cannot access '/home/rosamunda/.composer/': No such file or
> directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read more carefully, `./composer.json` is not `~/.composer`!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `composer init` before running `composer require ...`, this will create the composer.json file in the directory